# change icon/product name and image iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have given name of my application "Test" while creating my application/project in XCode 4.4.Now, I want to chage the name from "Test" to some other name.And also,I want to show an image in the icon.

I tried changing name in the **Target -> Product name** under packaging, But, its giving me error

```
Dependency error build setting product name undefined
```

How can I fix this?

Could any one please tell me the steps how can I change the product name and show an image in default icon, so that it will be shown when some one install my application on iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to rename your product.

- Select your `Targets` type `Product Name` on search bar. And Change the Product name.

[image: Rename Product]

- Change the name in `Info.plist` changing *Bundle Display Name* property from `${PRODUCT_NAME}` to the desired name.
- Go to **Xcode-->Project-->Rename**

Comment: I followed step 1 then 2, for step 3; I do not have such option(xcode->Project->Rename) in my XCode 4.4.1.Then, I build it, its showing me error : Build setting PRODUCT_NAME undefind.

Comment: @bapirout: Remove the $PRODUCT_NAME from the build settings

Comment: @bapirout: not three steps, three ways to do that. Do any of the above

Comment: If you will look into my question(bold section).I have already done the same thing and ended with error.And,I tried point no 2 given by you.still no success.

Comment: With 2nd option, that is changing "Bundle Display name" to desired name; the name vanished. That is, no name is displayed [only icon is displayed].Could any one please suggest?

Comment: @bapirout: did you add any name to info.plist ?

Comment: Well,The 2nd option worked for me.Previously I was writing my product name in between ${}, which I think wrong way of writing.Now, I changed this to; only product name[the name I wanted to give] and its working.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can changed it from main file name where all files are available like .h and .m  by single click on name of the project and then you can easily rename it and also can do this by click on edit schemes and then go to manage schemes and edit your project name. Hope it will helpful for u.

and for the icon image just name it **Icon.png** for iPhone 4 and for iPhone 5 just give the name **Icon@2x.png**, it will automatically set as icon image

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the name of the application that is being displayed on iPhone homescreen then go to "Target" settings, "info" tab and change the value of "bundle display name", and the name of your application will be changed.

For icon, add the icon image file in your project and change its name to "icon.png" and it will pick it up automatically.

Comment: ,thank for suggession.As per you,I'm able to display image in icon.But,If I'm changing bundle display name, nothing is changing.That is, the name is old(given at the time of application creation).